# Scroll to top jQuery in Rails 4 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've followed various tutorials on creating a fadeIn/Out jQuery scrollTo function. But there seems to be some conflict with the css display:none, as it's not showing on the page, if i remove the css display:none it shows the div, but obviously the fadeIn/Out does not work.

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .

    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
            $(".scrollToTop").fadeIn(1000)
        } else {
            $(".scrollToTop").fadeOut(1000);
        }
    });

    //Click event to scroll to top
    $(".scrollToTop").click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},500);
        return false;
    });
```

Other js code which works

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
        $(".navbar-transparent").addClass("navbar-color");
        $(".navbar-nav").addClass("navbar-nav-dark");
        $(".logo_dark").show();
        return $(".logo_light").hide();
      } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
        $(".navbar-transparent").removeClass("navbar-color");
        $(".navbar-nav").removeClass("navbar-nav-dark");
        $(".logo_light").show();
        return $(".logo_dark").hide();
      }
    });
```

CSS

```
.scrollToTop {
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 8.5%;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: rgba(100, 193, 151, .7);
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.scrollToTop:hover {
    background-color: rgba(100, 193, 151, 1);
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="scrollToTop"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i> Back to top</a>
```

Comment: Seems to be working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/swz9n5rc/). Is there any error? Can you explain what exactly happens at your end?

Comment: No errors and the div just doesn't show up at all, as in fade in.

Comment: Before the `If` add this `console.log($(this).scrollTop())` and check the console if scrollTop goes over 600.

Comment: Are you sure the js code is running? Can you put an alert inside and see?

Comment: I have other js code on the page working fine. I have another scroll to function which I've added above. Could this be conflicting?

Comment: It shouldn't be conflicting. You can add both code in one scroll function and check if that is running.

Comment: added the code into one, and the scrollToTop div didn't work. Might just scrap it.

Comment: It seems that your're not checking if the DOM was loaded. Have you tried wrapping your javascript code with the `ready` function?? http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is almost certainly because the browser has started processing your js before the DOM is finished loading so I'm guessing your `.scrollToTop` anchor is near the end of your HTML.

What you should do is bind events after the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
            $(".scrollToTop").fadeIn(1000)
        } else {
            $(".scrollToTop").fadeOut(1000);
        }
    });

    //Click event to scroll to top
    $(".scrollToTop").click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},500);
        return false;
    });
}
```

(You should do this for your code that is currently working as well or you may find that some users with slower computers have even more events that aren't bound to their objects)

**Side Note:** You shouldn't really be putting javascript into your `application.js` rather make a new asset like "init.js" and tell `application.js` to include it.

Comment: Thanks! Moving the script out of application.js solved the issue for me. Appreciate the help also @anpsmn